# Inject a dependency in an existing instance

Tags: ninject

I have the following classes:

The class to be injected with a dependency

```
public class ToBeInjected
{
    [Inject]
    public void InjectCommandParameters( IInjectParameters parameters )
    {
        // some set code here
    }
}
```

The dependency to be injected that implements `IInjectParameters`

and an injector

```
public class Injector
{
    public void SetParameters( ToBeInjected statement, IInjectParameters parameters )
    {
        statement.InjectCommandParameters(parameters);
    }
}
```

so what I try to achieve `statement.InjectCommandParameters(parameters)` by using ninject.

Comment: How about using `IKernel.Inject(ToBeInjected);`? See https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns. You would not even need the `Injector`

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I thought about that as well, I also think this `Injector` is completely unnecessary.